# Theoretical question about GAM (generalized additive models)

Tags: model-selection, model, generalized-additive-model

I'm new to GAM so please be patient with me.
This is a theoretical question rather than a coding question.
I have a model as follows:
response variable (y) = insect abundance;
Disturbance type (categorical fixed effect) with 3 levels;
Transect (categorical fixed effect) with 2 levels;
Distance (continuous variable); and
a series of explanatory variables, say E1:E10.
When I run model m1, that includes all variables (Y~Type + Transect + s(Distance) + s(E1) + ... + s(E10); R produces a table of the significance of the parametric estimators and the smoothers, which, if I understand correctly, is a rough indication of the importance of each with respect to explaining the variance in the response variable.
The next step is to reduce the model by removing explanatory variables that had little effect on understanding the variance of y. The strength of the new model can be ascertained using the AIC criterion (lower the AIC, the better the model).
My question is: when do you stop reducing the model? When you remove variables, often other variables become less important in the new model at explaining variance. Do you keep reducing the model until the AIC criterion stablizes? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Why are you fitting this model? For prediction? Or do you hope to learn something about the controls on your insect abundance. If the latter, you shouldn't be doing any model selection step-wise like this; we don't yet have good theory for doing post-selection inference for GAMs. One option is to fit the full model with `select = TRUE`, which will add additional penalties to shrink terms out of the model if warranted.

Comment: Thanks Gavin, I appreciate the comment. The goal of the analysis was to understand which variables influence insect abundance. Normally when I do analysis on abundance I use glmer and test for overdispersion using either Poisson or negative binomial (NB is almost always the best distribution). But in this particular study we noticed that insect abundance (our response variable) didn't seem to be linear wrt the explanatory variables, which lead us to using GAM. Maybe nlme would be a better option?